# Close command in side file from SeleniumIDE makes Jenkins job infinite while running with selenium-side-runner

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

### My Problem

---

I'm having an issue while trying to execute a **.side** file using **selenium-side-runner** in a Jenkins job.

Here's the line that I use in a **"Execute Windows batch command"** step in my Jenkins job :

```bash
selenium-side-runner --output-directory=results -c "browserName=firefox" ./Test.side
```

Also, using **SeleniumIDE** I generated a side file which just open and then close a web page and when I run the job it just runs indefinitely **BUT** it's saying in the **Console Output** that **"Finished test Test01 Success"**. However, when I run it while it's just having an open command it ends and makes my job build successful.

I think it won't help but here's my **.side simple test file** :

```js
{
  "id": "70911e9f-53a2-4613-83a5-47ffae039816",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "Project",
  "url": "https://stackoverflow.com",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "097e734e-fb82-4d47-ae88-bbdc893c7f25",
    "name": "Test01",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "405f2292-ba88-4e6c-a4fb-0e974da7f8b5",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "/",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    },
    // If I just delete the above bloc with the close command, it works
    {
      "id": "a431e9ef-3fc1-4cc5-a613-e35caf80c27a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "close",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "7230ef0e-6808-4f5e-bf84-d15521a08be4",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["097e734e-fb82-4d47-ae88-bbdc893c7f25"]
  }],
  "urls": ["https://stackoverflow.com/"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

### What I tried

---

I also tried with bigger **files with multiples commands** (login to a website, then logout, verify the title, ...) and I'm having the same issue. When I run it using close command at the end it's never ending and when I delete it, it works correctly.

### My Questions

---

- Is there a way to use the close command or is it just normal that it doesn't work in Jenkins job but working while running it inside SeleniumIDE ?
- Is it okay to avoid using it if it just doesn't work at all ?